# as.POSIXct returning NA

Tags: r

I have a little csv file that looks like this in which the time column look like this:

```
Gmt_time <chr>
-----------------------
03.11.2015 00:00:00.000
03.11.2015 01:00:00.000
03.11.2015 02:00:00.000
```

When I upgrade the column to put it as.POSIXct with the function:

```
hourly_data$Gmt_time = as.POSIXct(hourly_data$Gmt_time, format ="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
```

It stays like this :

```
Gmt_time
<S3: POSIXct>
<NA>
<NA>
<NA>
```

Does anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: The format %Y-%m-%d says the first part of the date is the year, the next part is the month and the next is the day. It also says the parts are separated by dash.  Clearly these are not the case.  In the format string order them correctly and use dot instead of dash so that the format string and data correspond.

Comment: Man you are so right, I'm really sorry to had been such a dumb.

Comment: We all do it from time to time ...

Comment: I corrected it, but still the same

Comment: currently is this format ="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%OS3"

Comment: format ="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%OS3"

Comment: Remove the 3 from `OS3`. Check the result with `dput` to see that the right decimals are there.

Comment: Totally fine, just after removing the 3 from os3, everything working very well Sir thank you very much